# jQuery: display result in text box

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/uRCL2/1

At the moment the result is shown in two span tags, what do I need change to join the two and show as a value in the text box with the `id=sku`?

---

JS:

```
 $("#options").change(function(){
 switch($(this).val()){
    case "3370":
         $(".display_text_here").text('TB');
    break;
    case "3371":
         $(".display_text_here").text('LT');
    break;
    case "3375":
         $(".display_text_here").text('LTR');
    break;
    case "3372":
          $(".display_text_here").text('BO');
    break;
    case "3373":
         $(".display_text_here").text('MC');
    break;
    case "3374":
         $(".display_text_here").text('NC');
    break;
    case "3376":
          $(".display_text_here").text('STA');
    break;

  }
 });
 $("#options2").change(function(){
  switch($(this).val()){
    case "3423":
          $(".display_text_here2").text('12');
    break;
    case "3424":
         $(".display_text_here2").text('24');
    break;
    case "3425":
         $(".display_text_here2").text('48');
    break;

 }
 });
```

​
HTML:

```
<select id="options">
<option value="">Choose...</option>   
<option value="3370" >Tight Buffered </option>
<option value="3371" >Loose Tube 900um </option>
<option value="3375" >Loose Tube 2mm </option>
<option value="3372" >Break-Out 2mm </option>
<option value="3373" >Micro Cable 2mm </option>
<option value="3374" >Nano Cable 900um </option>                                                    
<option value="3376" >Steel Tape Armoured 900um </option>
</select>
<select id="options2">
  <option value="">Choose...</option>
  <option value="3423" >12 MC</option>
  <option value="3424" >24 MC</option>
  <option value="3425" >48 MC</option>
</select>
<br />

<span class="display_text_here"></span><span class="display_text_here2"></span>
<br />

<input type="text" id="sku">​
```

Comment: The result is shown in a div, and there is no text box. Also, please post the code in your question rather than just on jsfiddle.

Comment: "join the two and show as a value in the text box" - what "two"? Can you give an example of what you'd like the end result to look like?

Comment: Textbox? Two span tags? Are you sure you posted the right code?

Comment: Updated, hadn't updated the jsfiddle!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the value for each part in a variable and assign both on change like you can see [on this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/AkxCh/).

Comment: That works well, then if I have another option to add I can just build up the value by adding +sku_part3 ?

Comment: @VincePettit Good! And yes, if you want another option just add +sku_part3, just keep in mind that if the user selects the option "Choose...", the value will stay there, so I'd advice you to add a default case to your switch to make the variable empty in case they select the option "Choose..."

Comment: Take a look at my solution.  I've refactored it a bit more, putting it in a function.  That way, you're updating a single function rather than multiple occurrences as the scope grows.

Comment: @darkajax If I added a textbox, how would that work with being added to the end of the sku? See http://jsfiddle.net/AkxCh/4/ with added Length textbox

Comment: @VincePettit You can do it the same way, but you wouldn't need the switch: [jsfiddle.net/darkajax/FHZBy/](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/FHZBy/), just keep in mind that since now you're using so many variables, it could be a good idea to use an array instead...

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<input type="text" name="sku" id="sku"/>
```

js:

```
#options
     case "3370":
         $("#sku").val('TB'+$("#sku").val());
        break;

#options2
   $("#sku").val($("#sku").val()+'24');
```

Comment: This works for one, but if you see my updated question I need to combine two values in to one text box

Comment: Also I've just seen an issue with this, if the value of the first and second boxes are set then the first select box is changed the original value remains in the box. See http://jsfiddle.net/uRCL2/3/

Comment: @VincePettit do you want to update the value of the txtbox if the first select get changed

Answer (score 1):

I took some liberties with your code.  Here's a solution that involves less repetition:  http://jsfiddle.net/ReeaN/

HTML

```
<select id="options">
    <option value="">Choose...</option>
    <option value="3370" data-code="TB" >Tight Buffered </option>
    <option value="3371" data-code="LT">Loose Tube 900um </option>
    <option value="3375" data-code="LTR">Loose Tube 2mm </option>
    <option value="3372" data-code="BO">Break-Out 2mm </option>
    <option value="3373" data-code="MC">Micro Cable 2mm </option>
    <option value="3374" data-code="NC">Nano Cable 900um </option>
    <option value="3376" data-code="STA">Steel Tape Armoured 900um </option>
</select>
<select id="options2">
  <option value="">Choose...</option>
  <option value="3423">12 MC</option>
  <option value="3424">24 MC</option>
  <option value="3425">48 MC</option>
</select>
<br />

<span class="display_text_here"></span><span class="display_text_here2"></span>
<br />

<input type="text" id="sku">
```

Javascript:

```
$("#options").change(function(){
    var val = '';
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        val = $(this).find('option:selected').data('code');
    }
    $(".display_text_here").text(val);
    updateDisplay();
});
$("#options2").change(function(){
    var val = '';
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        val = $(this).find('option:selected').text().split(' ')[0];
    }
    $(".display_text_here2").text(val);
    updateDisplay();
});

function updateDisplay() {
    $('#sku').val($(".display_text_here").text() + $(".display_text_here2").text());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change add the `data-code="TB"` section to the option as the options are generated elsewhere. Thanks for the effort though, would be perfect if I could.

Comment: Oh well, it was an interesting exercise anyway.  You might consider switching to a Javascript hash table to look up the codes if the data is going to change over time.  Otherwise, you'll be maintaining your case statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".display_text_here").append('TB');
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the results seem to be shown in 1 `div` not 2 `span` tags. However to change the results an example is to add the `textbox` obviously and amend:

```
$(".display_text_here").text('TB');
```

to:

```
$("#sku").val('TB');
```